# Can a function have more than one input?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my Differential Equations textbook, it says that First-Order ODEs can be written as:

M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0

Then, it gives an example:

(y - x)dx + 4xdy = 0

I assume M(x,y) = (y - x) , but I do not understand why N(x ,y)=4x

The reason why I do not understand is because N(x,y) only has x as a variable. So why is it written with that notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state than $N$ is a function of two variables thanks to the symbol $N(x,y)$.

For example $$N(x,y)=4x+a\,y$$ where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

This is valid any value of $a$, for example $a=0$.
$$N(x,y)=4x+0 \: y=4x$$
$$N(x,y)=4x$$
Thus $N(x,y)=4x$ is a particular case of a two variable function.

Of course, this is only one example taken among many. Nobody forbid to state that a two variable function $M(x,y)$ be equal to a single variable function $f(x)$, in stating that $N(x,y)=f(x)$. Just imagine that among the parameters included in the function $N(x,y)$ there is a parameter nul as coefficient of $y$.

This is the same for a one variable function which can be the constant function. I am sure that you are familiar with the constant function : $$f(x)=c$$
The variable $x$ doesn't appears into the function in this particular case. This does not mean that the function doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

A first order differential equation can be written as $M(x, y) \ dx + N(x, y) \ dy = 0$, but the functions $M$ and $N$ need not be functions of two variables. Indeed, they may be functions of a single variable - a special case can be seen in some separable equations:

$$ e^x \ dx - y \ dy = 0$$

This is separable, and, as a bonus, the coefficients $M$ and $N$ are functions of a single variable.

Comment: So when it states a function as M(x,y), it can be M(x), M(y) or M(x,y)?

Comment: It can, but to be general, we specify it as a function of two variables. If you haven't taken a course in calculus in several variables, this may be foreign to you.

Comment: (-1) This doesn't answer OP's question